# How to print a list of possible matches from C-n?

Tags: autocompletion

That is, doing autocompletition with C-n, is there a way to obtain the list of possible matches, same as returned into the popup menu ?

Given the example below

[image]

is it possible to retrieve {aaa, aaab, ababa} from a vim inner list ?
In other words, where these matches are stored ?

Answer (score 4):

If your Vim binary includes the patch [8.1.1068](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.1068), you can use [`complete_info()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#complete_info()). To get the list of all matches, while the pum is visible, you could use it like this:

```
map(get(complete_info(['items']), 'items', {}), {_,v -> v.word})
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

If your Vim binary also includes [8.1.1803](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.1803), you can rewrite the expression in a more readable way, using the method call operator:

```
complete_info(['items'])->get('items', {})->map({_,v -> v.word})
                        ^^                ^^
```

---

As an example, this installs a `C-x C-x` mapping which – when pressed while the pum is visible – will assign the list of completion matches to the variable `g:matches`:

```
ino <silent> <c-x><c-x> <c-r>=<sid>get_list_of_matches()<cr>
fu s:get_list_of_matches() abort
    if ! pumvisible() | return '' | endif
    let g:matches = complete_info(['items'])->get('items', {})->map({_,v -> v.word})
    return ''
endfu
```

---

Instead of assigning the variable manually (via a mapping), you can also assign it automatically, by installing an autocmd listening to the `CompleteChanged` event, provided your Vim binary includes [8.1.1138](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.1138):

```
augroup get_list_of_matches
    au!
    au CompleteChanged * let g:matches = complete_info(['items'])->get('items', {})->map({_,v -> v.word})
augroup END
```

---

For more info, see:

```
:h complete_info(
:h CompleteChanged
```